Implementing restrictions via multiple links into dijkstra routing algorithm
I have successfully implemented a Dijkstra algorithm for finding optimal routes in road networks. I have constructed the data so that there are no "nodes", instead I use road segments, and the segments have links to all other connected road segments.
Turn restrictions from one road segment to another road segments are very simple to implement (if restricted turn found, then just don't add that link to the open links priority queue).
However, my road network contains more complex turn restrictions (or restricted "driving manoeuvres"):


How could I take this kind of restrictions into accout with Dijkstra, where route from 0 to 5 via 1-2-3-4 is not allowed, but route from 0 to 5 via 6-7-8 is allowed? Or is this even possible with Dijkstra?

What exactly determines the restriction? Is it the combination of source (0) and target (5) or is it only determined by the source? Or something else?

@trincot I don't quite understand your question.. driving restrictions are specified so that you cannot travel from one segment to some other segment VIA specified segments, for example you cannot come to highway from one ramp on the left side of the highway and then exit from the next ramp nearby to right, because you would be hopping over let's say 6 lanes and cause a traffic accident.. :)

Let me put it differently. If I want to go from 0 to 2, will it be allowed via 1? If I want to go from 2 to 4, will it be allowed via 3? What exactly is the atomic restriction in your example?

Ah, yes, the only restriction here is 1-2-3-4-5, so if we start from 2, it's perfectly legal to go 2-3-4-5.

@trincot I edited the picture to give better understanding of the problem and also added another example

How is it different from the turn restrictions you already applied?

Isn't it enough to say that from 3 you can only go to 9 and from 8 you can only go to 4?

@marcell yes, it's actually enough for the example 1 to say you an only go 3 to 9 and 8 to 4, but for the second example, it's not anymore that simple, because there can be many routes that go from 2 to 3, but only one route (1,2,3) is restricted.
